# Create json string dynamically using a function in C++

Tags: c++, json, c++11, boost

I want to create a json string using C++ function like a simple example below:

```
string createJson(string one, string two, string three, string four)
{
    boost::proprty_tree::ptree pt;
    std::stringstream ss;

    pt.put("one", one);
    pt.put("two", two);
    pt.put("three", three);
    pt.put("four", four);

    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    string jsonstr, tempstr;
    //assume one below are initialised any strings
    string one, two, three, four;
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        tempstr = createJson(one, two, three, four);
        jsonstr.append(tempstr);
    }
    cout << jsonstr << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be in proper json format. But somewhere I am getting improper json format when all loops run. The json needs to be sent to client application from server and should be processed with json form only. Is it the right way to do it?

Please feel free to assume json values(int, string etc).

Comment: What is jsonstr? Is that part of a library?

Comment: `boost::property_tree`'s purpose is not json... There are dedicated json libraries ...

Comment: This code doesn't output anything at all. No data is even put streamed into `ss`. Please post code that you have verified actually produces the phenomenon you are describing. There even is a typo in `proprty_tree`, so there's no way the code you are showing can be the code you are talking about.

Comment: This might be the question, but I don't see `ss` being written to.

Comment: nlohmann::json is a brilliant header only C++ json library

Answer (score 0):

In the code shown the only missing line seems to be

```
write_json(ss, pt);
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da00dcc5dd1bc8bb)**

### HOWEVER

Use a proper JSON library!

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>

std::string createJson(std::string const& one, std::string const& two,
                       std::string const& three, std::string const& four)
{
    return serialize(boost::json::object{
        {"one", one},
        {"two", two},
        {"three", three},
        {"four", four},
    });
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0686e531319e6af)** as well